# Hide NavBar When Displaying Popup With React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I am ultimately trying to hide my bootstrap navbar which has `position: sticky-top` when I show a pop up slideshow. I am using react. I have tried selecting for the navbar element in my on click handler and changing the display but this doesn't work. It removed the navbar when showing the slideshow but then fails to add it back when the slideshow is closed. I suspect it might be because the navbar does not re render? Since the pop up is not a child of the navbar I cannot pass state to it. I also have stopped propagation in child elements to prevent closing the slideshow which also could be a problem?

**my on-click handler:**

```
  toggleSlideVisibility = () => {
    const largeNav = document.getElementById("largeNav");
    if (largeNav.style.display === "none") {
      largeNav.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      largeNav.style.display = "none";
    }
    console.log(largeNav.style.display);
    this.setState({ slidesVisible: !this.state.slidesVisible });
  };
```

**my slideshow with a modal:**

```
<div className="modalView" onClick={props.toggle}>
  <div
    id="vintageSlideShow"
    className="carousel slide"
    data-ride="carousel"
    onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
  >
    <ol className="carousel-indicators">
      <li
        data-target="#vintageSlideShow"
        data-slide-to="0"
        className="active"
      ></li>
      <li data-target="#vintageSlideShow" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#vintageSlideShow" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#vintageSlideShow" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div className="carousel-inner">
      <div className="carousel-item active">
        <img
          className="d-block img-responsive"
          src={image1}
          alt="First"
          onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-item ">
        <img className="d-block img-responsive" src={image2} alt="Second" />
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-item ">
        <img className="d-block img-responsive" src={image3} alt="Third" />
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-item ">
        <img className="d-block img-responsive" src={image4} alt="Fourth" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span className="closer" onClick={props.toggle}>
    close
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: post navbar code as well..also better if possible to provide full code of modal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you use redux, but if you do you can store the global state in a reducer. If not, you can also use React context to store your global state. When you want your navbar to disappear you can call an action.

```
// example

this.props.hideNav();
```

Answer (score 0):

When modal button is pressed (within the modal component), we need to communicate this to the parent which can toggle the navigation visibility by changing the class which houses the navigation;

relevant **CSS**:

```
.showBar{display:block}
.hideBar{display:none;}
```

relevant **parent JS**:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      navVisible: true
    };
  }

  toggleNavVisibility = () => {
    this.state.navVisible
      ? this.setState({ navVisible: false })
      : this.setState({ navVisible: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mainContent">
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <div className={this.state.navVisible ? "showBar" : "hideBar"}>
          <TopBar />
        </div>
        <section>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus
          <br />
          <ModalExample
            buttonLabel={"launch Modal"}
            className={"simple"}
            modalTitle="My slide show"
            onModalClick={this.toggleNavVisibility.bind(this)}
          />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

relevant **modal component**:

```
const ModalExample = props => {
  const { buttonLabel, className, modalTitle, onModalClick } = props;

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
    onModalClick();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button color="danger" onClick={toggle}>
        {buttonLabel}
      </Button>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} className={className}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{modalTitle}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>This is where you can have your slideshow...</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle}>
            Do Something
          </Button>{" "}
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xkk7v1)